# Get context-param in asynchronous method seam

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, seam, facescontext

I want to get a context-param configure in my web.xml. In a method call normally (with seam 2.2.0), I do this:

```
readDirectory = (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getInitParameter(
                        "ReadDirectory");
```

It's work fine, but in asynchronous method (@Asynchronous) my faceContext is null.

So I don't know how to get this param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it:

```
ServletLifecycle.getServletContext().getInitParameter("ReadDirectory");
```

Easy when you know ^^